# Remove table of contents from a R bookdown to pdf_book or pdf_document2

Tags: latex, rstudio, r-markdown, bookdown, miktex

I compiling a short document using bookdown in Rstudio. I would simply like to drop the table of contents at the beginning of the document.  I could "knit to pdf" instead of "knit to pdf_book" or "knit to pdf_document2", but then would loose a lot of the bookdown functions (cross references etc.).

Should be fairly easy, isn't it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
---
title: "MWE"
output:
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    toc: false
---
```

It also works with `pdf_document2`:

```
---
title: "MWE"
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    toc: false
---
```